# Can I run an Android jenkins job in existing environment?

Tags: jenkins

I want run my first Android Jenkins Job in an existing setup.

I referred to some site in Google – they are suggesting like create a new node for Android Jobs. Is it really necessary to create a new Node??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not "necessary". If your existing Jenkins setup runs on an OS that can support Android SDK, there is no need for a "special" node, until you get into performance issues with hundreds of concurrent jobs.